# Center a div container without setting width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my div responsively. But I am unable to do it without setting a width...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left box">Content</div>
        <div class="right box">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {text-align:center}
.container {width:100%; margin: 10px auto}
.left {width:69%;max-width:350px; background:blue}
.right {width:29%;max-width:150px; background:red}
.box {float:left;padding:20px}
```

How can I keep the `.container` in the middle ?

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/z9zydnwL/

Comment: `.container` is 100% wide, thus, technically it IS centered, but taking up the whole width.

Comment: @Debayjyoti Das like this http://jsfiddle.net/z9zydnwL/4/

Comment: You have to set div in center of page without using width property and still you are accepted answer which contains width property. This is totally wrong. You have accepted wrong answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) can even center floated children!

So I can simply add `display:flex` and `justify-content: center;` to the container

```
.container {
    margin: 10px auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/z9zydnwL/6/)**

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) these days is also good

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}
.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
}
.left {
  width: 69%;
  max-width: 350px;
  background: blue
}
.right {
  width: 29%;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: red
}
.box {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left box">Content</div>
    <div class="right box">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much better, I noticed in other solutions `:inline` the blocks were breaking off at max-width due to the % and padding. But flex handles this, Why was this happening ?

Answer (score 15):

One solution is to replace float with inline-block:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center
}
.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 0;
}
.left {
  width: 69%;
  max-width: 350px;
  background: blue
}
.right {
  width: 29%;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: red
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left box">Content</div>
    <div class="right box">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But question is about without using width property but you have used the width property

Comment: Can you explain why is totally wrong(because your comment about width is wrong)?

Comment: because in question they have said that " unable to do it without setting a width" so meaning is that they want to set it in center without using width property but in your answer you have used width

Comment: but you have used it.

Answer (score 8):

i think you should use the below css

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}
.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 0;
}
.left {
  width: 69%;
  max-width: 350px;
  background: blue
}
.right {
  width: 29%;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: red
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left box">Content</div>
        <div class="right box">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can put a div in center without using width property as per your need.

Say you have some content with variable width. If it is just text, you can probably get away with `text-align:center`. But say it is an image, and that image may have different dimensions. How do you consistently center it on the page?

First, put the content inside a floated div, because floated divs will shrink wrap around the content. Second, wrap that div in another floated div.

Now here's the good part. Relatively position the outer float (yellow) `left:50%`, so that the left edge is at the middle of the page. Then relatively position the inner float (red) `left:-50%` to shift it exactly 1/2 of the yellow div's width to the left, so that it is centered. Note that the yellow div and the red div are exactly the same width, because the yellow is also a float, so it is shrink wrapped to fit around the red one.

The background colors and heights are included to make it clear what is happening. Normally, the yellow div would have no height spec and no padding, and would be set to your background color. The red div is the one that we are trying to center.

For reference you can check link
http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm

Sample example to show how it works

```css
    .container
     {
      float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: 50%;
            padding-top: 10px;
     }
     .center {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: -50%;
            background: red;

    }
```

```html
    <div class="main_container">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="center">sample content</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
     </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The reference URL mentioned  is no longer available.

Answer (score 5):

You are having the padding value in `.box`. So, the left and right boxes width wouldn't fit as well. Try reducing the width value then it must works:

```
.wrapper {text-align:center}
.container {width:100%; margin: 10px auto}
.left {width:67%;max-width:350px; background:blue}
.right {width:27%;max-width:150px; background:red}
.box {float:left;padding:20px}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the below style by replacing your float left with `display: inline-block;`

```
.wrapper {width:100%; text-align:center}
.container {margin: 10px auto; font-size: 0}
.left {width:69%;max-width:350px; background:blue}
.right {width:29%;max-width:150px; background:red}
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px; 
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9zydnwL/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of floating the boxes, use

```
display: inline-block;
```

See the ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9zydnwL/1/)***.